# Problema de escopo em namespace e classe, C++

Tags: c++, namespace, scope

Eu tentei criar uma classe de complexos em um namespace do C++ por exercício, mas quando tento definir alguns métodos da minha classe, o compilador retorna erro.

Meu código:

complex.h:

```
#ifndef COMPLEX_N_H
#define COMPLEX_N_H
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

namespace complex_number{
    class complex_N{
    public:
        virtual double real() const;
        virtual double imag() const;
        virtual double module() const;
        virtual double arg() const;
        virtual const complex_N operator +(const complex_N& z);
        virtual const complex_N operator -(const complex_N& z);
        virtual const complex_N operator *(const complex_N& z);
        virtual const complex_N operator /(const complex_N& z);
        virtual const bool operator ==(const complex_N& z);
        ostream& operator <<(ostream& outputStream);
    };
}


#endif // COMPLEX_H
```

complex_e.h:

```
#ifndef COMPLEX_E_H
#define COMPLEX_E_H
#include "complex.h"

namespace complex_number{
    class complex_e : public complex_N {
    public:
        complex_e();
        complex_e(double a);
        complex_e(double a, double b);
        double real() const;
        double imag() const;
        double module() const;
        double arg() const;
        complex_e conj() const;
        const complex_e operator +(const complex_e& z);
        const complex_e operator -(const complex_e& z);
        const complex_e operator *(const complex_e& z);
        const complex_e operator /(const complex_e& z);
        const bool operator ==(const complex_e& z);
    private:
        double re_;
        double im_;
    };
}

#endif
```

complex_e.cpp:

```
#include "complex_e.h"

complex_number::complex_e::complex_e():re_(0), im_(0){

}

complex_number::complex_e::complex_e(double a):re_(a), im_(0){

}

complex_number::complex_e::complex_e(double a, double b):re_(a), im_(b){

}

double complex_number::complex_e::real(){
    return re_;
}

double complex_number::complex_e::imag(){
    return im_;
}

double complex_number::complex_e::module(){
    return sqrt(re_*re_+im_*im_);
}

double complex_number::complex_e::arg(){
    return atan(im_/re_);
}

complex_number::complex_e complex_number::complex_e::conj(){
    return complex_number::complex_e(re_,-im_);
};

const complex_number::complex_e operator+(const complex_number::complex_e& z){
    return(complex_number::complex_e(z.re_+re_, z.im_+im_));
}

const complex_number::complex_e operator-(const complex_number::complex_e& z){
    return(complex_number::complex_e(re_-z.re_, im_-z.im_));
}
```

Quando eu tento compilar esse código eu recebo erros como:

> Erro 1: no declaration matches 'double
> complex_number::complex_e::real()'

> Erro 2: no declaration matches
> 'double complex_number::complex_e::imag()'

Para todas as funções definidas no complex_e.cpp, exceto os construtores e operadores.

Enquanto isso, nos operadores que eu defini eu recebo erros como:

> error: 're_' was not declared in this scope
>
> error: 'im_' was not declared in this scope

Quando re_ e im_ deveriam ser os atributos privados do objeto que chama os construtores.

Comment: Como ficou o cpp de `complex_N` ?

Comment: Em `complex_e.cpp` deve usar o mesmo `namespace`. É para isso que existe. `complex_number` só existe nesse `namespace`, mas poderia existir em vários. E se declara um método `const` no header deve declarar igual no `cpp`. Isso é overloading, podem existir versões `const` e não `const` e o compilador não vai saber qual está faltando, já que vai esperar por 2 e 2 no header e no cpp

Comment: arfneto, muito obrigado, resolveu meu problema com os "no declaration matches".